# Laravel 4 - how to get meaningful errors

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

This is the first time I'm developing locally on a Windows machine.  On MAMP I used to receive meaningful error messages but the code below is giving me errors which I cannot decipher.

```
$user = User::find(10);
Auth::login($user);
```

Error in exception handler: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /home/vagrant/Code/projectname/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Environment.php:117

How do I get the default 'orange' laravel error page, and why does this simple authentication not work?

Comment: Set `debug` to true in your `app.php` config file.

Comment: I changed it to true but it still returns an ugly error screen.

Comment: Make sure you don't have local config file, that has `debug=false` etc. Can't tell you this. But I can tell you for sure, that the error is not in the lines you pasted. Look in the `View::make`, for it is the culprit.

Comment: I have debug bar installed and hitting messages gave me the 'meaningful' errors I was looking for.  Shame the pages initially displays the ugly error screen.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your enviroment isn't set up correctly.

try typing the following into terminal.app

```
 hostname
```

This will give you your machines hostname, copy this and paste it in *\bootstrap\start.php* in the *detectEnvironment()* function.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Detect The Application Environment
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel takes a dead simple approach to your application environments
| so you can just specify a machine name for the host that matches a
| given environment, then we will automatically detect it for you.
|
*/

$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(

    'local' => array('homestead'),

));
```

replace the string 'homestead' with your hostname. Hope this will give you your pretty errors back.